# Compare two partitions of a dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have the following task: I have a dataframe with let's say 200 numerical und 200 character variables and 2 partitions and I should compare these two partitions regarding each variable. So for numerical variables I can calculate e.g. Pearson correlation or KS-statistic between partitions and for character I can calculate kappa or Cramer's V. It's not so difficult to write the corresponding code, but perphaps there is some useful package already in the wolrd. It's quite a common task, I think (e.g. if partitions are time stamps and the dataframe has historical data over some period of time). So the question is: does someone know any package for this?
Thanks in advance.

PS. If it isn't clear what I mean. The dataframe is organized as follows (only it has much more variables and much more id's), part is the partition variable, it has values 0 and 1.

[image: structure of the dataframe]

Comment: try looking into `scypi`

Answer (score 0):

The [scikit-learn metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics) library has all kinds of functions that use array input.

What confuses me is that you want to compare 'variables'. Typically 'variables' are inputs in order to obtain 'predictions'. You then obtain metrics on those predictions.

Assuming you still want to calculate for example the f1-score on the 'variables', you could split the partitions into separate dataframes and for example run:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
f1score = f1_score(df1["ads"].to_numpy().flatten(), df2["ads"].to_numpy().flatten())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm not speaking about predictions, my task has nothing to do with machine learning. I only have to monitor changes in the historical data. You can see it as follows: I have a table where each week some data are updated and I have to compare the new week with the old week to see if there are sudden large changes in some variables.